# Flutter Autocomplete widget not showing when fieldViewBuilder is added with custom textfield

Tags: flutter

The autocomplete data stop showing up when fieldViewBuilder property is added with custom textfield.

Everything works fine when `fieldViewBuilder` was not added.

```
                        Autocomplete<Suggestion>(
                            displayStringForOption: _displayStringForOption,
                            optionsBuilder:
                                (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) async {
                              if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                                return const Iterable<Suggestion>.empty();
                              }
                              await model
                                  .handleSuggestion(textEditingValue.text);

                              return model.suggestions
                                  .where((Suggestion option) {
                                return option.description
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(
                                        textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                              });
                            },
                            onSelected: (Suggestion selection) {
                              debugPrint(
                                  'You just selected ${_displayStringForOption(selection)}');
                            },
                            fieldViewBuilder: (context, textEditingController,
                                    focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) =>
                                const InputField(),
                          )
```

That's my code

Answer (score 4):

I never knew the answers was looking at me.

assigned `controller: textEditingController, focusnode: focusNode, onTap: onFieldSubmitted`

```
                   fieldViewBuilder: (context, textEditingController,
                                    focusNode, onFieldSubmitted) =>
                                InputField(
                              controller: textEditingController,
                              focusnode: focusNode,
                              onTap: onFieldSubmitted,
                            ),
```

Above snippet fixed my issue.